# 2015 MBP shutdown/boot problems - "X86PlatformPlugin Result 0" messages

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave

I have a 2015 15" MacBook Pro (full specs- i7, GPU, 1 TB) running latest Mojave. I have verbose mode enabled for shutdown/boot.

Basically, shutdown and boot sometimes take minutes (occasionally five or more) - during that time the console just displays `X86PlatformPlugin Result 0` messages over and over (and over).

Resetting the SMC tends to reduce the time, but it eventually starts to happen again.

I'm trying to avoid having to do a complete wipe and install.

Anyone have insight on what this message means and what is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem for 2 years across 3 different Macbook Pros. I think it has something to do with the OWC Thunderbolt 3 Dock. 
If I unplug the dock during boot or shutdown, all those `X86PlatformPlugin Result 0` messages go away and everything speeds up.

**[edit]**

I found the problem!

I have a collection of OWC USB3-to-eSATA adapters. One (older Western Digital) drive enclosure is very fussy and apparently had a particular issue with one of the adapter-cable combinations. I swapped out the eSATA cable & adapter for a different set, rebooted the enclosure and viola, everything is happy again.
My theory is that this error at boot/shutdown is indicating an external hardware fault.

The troublesome device tree in my case is Mac > TB3 Dock > USB3 Hub > eSATA Adapter > WD Drive bay

This discovery was *after* I removed all the 3rd party extensions from my system on a brand new (1 day old) 2019 MBP to no avail.

It should be noted that the WD drive bay was powered down while all this trouble was happening, which suggests that there's still a keep-alive charge running for active sensing to detect plug-replug behaviour

Comment: thanks - I do use an external dock (Caldigit TB2 dock), but this happens even when the MBP is not connected to any external devices.

Comment: That's weird, when I was dealing with the issue, the first thing I went after was all the 3rd party inits inside:
/System/Library/Extensions, 
/Library/Extensions, 
/Library/LaunchAgents, 
/Library/LaunchDaemons, 
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools,

Answer (score 0):

I also had this verbose message "X86PlatformPlugin Result 0".

Culprit was Seagate external drive (Expansion Desktop Drive 4Tb, model SRD00F2).

Seems impossible to fixit. I change of backup drive. Now this message is gone, fluidity is here again.